# Distributed/Parallel testing using selenium grid plugin for Jenkins

Tags: python, selenium, jenkins

I want to run python Selenium script in parallel / Distributed across machines A(Master) and Machine B(slave).

Steps I followed:
1.Jenkins is deployed successfully on machine A.
2.selenium grid plug in is installed.
3.[Step by step guide to set up master and slave machines](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines) is completed successfully.
4.After completing above 3 steps, I wanted to configure selenium grid plugin part i.e
[Selenium Grid deployment on Jenkins cluster](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Selenium+Plugin)

I am not able to understand anything further :( 
namely ( few words from the page) : "Connecting to Selenium Grid
When you run selenium tests in stand-alone Selenium, you specify the type of the browser in the constructor.

```
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://jenkins.mydomain:4444/wd/hub"), capability);"
```

In above sentence what is constructor and further more where exactly i need to metion the `"WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver..."` in my python selenium script or in JENKINS. Moreover I don't find any detailed configurationsteps of selenium grid plugin. Looking forward for someone who can provide me detailed explanation about setting up the selenium grid plugin and execute parallel runs.Finally do i need to "create a job" after configuration of selenium grid in JENKINS is completed?